# cakephp avoid multiple callbacks

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Suppose I have a `User` model who `hasMany` `Items` (and `Item` `belongsTo` `User`, of course)

each time an `Item` is modified anyewhere in my applicationI want an email to be sent to his user (or to their users)

So in my Item model I wrote something like

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    // if data is modified find User and send him email
}
```

But making so when I edit more than one Item at the same time in my action (i.e. in a foreach loop) then several emails are sent, but I want just one email, or one email for every User involved in the update.

How can I achieve this?

Maybe using cakephp Event system?

Comment: I edited. In one of my action I have to loop through the Items and save them one by one. In this way many callbacks are triggered

Comment: if you use `saveMany` you can have the option to set callbacks to false.

Comment: I do want callbacks to be triggered. If I use saveMany is the beforeSave callback triggered just one time or as many times as the Item number? (by the way I can't use saveMany because I have to do a logic that loops through the Items)

Comment: I managed to remove my foreach cicle and use a saveMany call instead. But beforeSave is still called two times if I'm saving two Items

Comment: sorry i think we can't set callbacks to false using `saveMany`, using `saveField` you can set callbacks to false

Answer (score 0):

You can set an extra variable:

```
public $isMultiple = false;
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    if(!$this->isMultiple) {
        $this->isMultiple = true;
        // if data is modified find User and send him email
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't send email from inside a data model. Email activities are very volatile and you should keep your data model code as stable as possible. Instead, use a component and call a method on the component when you need emails sent.

It sounds like you want to report on completed transactions, and not individual record edits. One way to handle this is to set a datetime stamp in the User model of when the last email was sent. You can then use that datetime stamp to find Item records that have been modified, and notify of those changes.

In your controller you would simply modify the items as needed.

```
public function action()
{
    foreach($record in $records)
    {
        ......
        $this->Item->save(....);
    }

    $this->MyEmailComponent->notify($user_id);
}
```

Then in your email component you would query the Item model for which items have changed since the last email was sent.

```
public function notify($user_id)
{
    $this->User->id = $user_id;
    $last_email = $this->User->field('emailed');

    $updated_items = $this->Item->find('all',array(
        'conditions'=>array('Item.updated >'=>$last_email)
    ));

    // send email about those items

    $this->User->saveField('emailed',date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
}
```

Comment: your solution works, but I have many actions that modify Items so I need to use callbacks: I don't want to repeat the `MyEmailComponent->notify` code at the end of every action. And if I add another action I don't want to remember to add the line. this is what callbacks are meant to, I think